# How do i autorun .command files from a USB drive when I plug it in?

Tags: terminal, usb

I've made two .command files, "lock" and "unlock". The first hides hidden files with: `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`, then refreshes finder with `killall Finder`. The second does the opposite, I simply replaced `TRUE` with `FALSE`, in the first command.

I'd like to copy these over to a USB thumb drive in such a way that when I plug this USB into my laptop, it automatically executes the "unlock" file, and as soon as I unplug it, the "lock" file is executed.

I don't know to what extent this is possible and what drawbacks/problems it may entail, but any help or input is very much appreciated. I'm also only doing this for fun, so I'm perfectly okay with experimenting!

Comment: Keyboard Maestro 6 apparently has a feature like this, but I haven't used it yet. There's also EventScripts: http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/EventScripts.html which may be able to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A `launchd` service supports the WatchPaths option, which launches a program when the contents of a folder are changed:

> WatchPaths <array of strings>
>        This optional key causes the job to be started if any one of the listed paths are modified.

By watching /Volumes, a shell script can be created which would check whether your external disk is mounted or not° and run the appropriate commands°°.

° The simplest way would be checking for the presence of a /Volumes/disk-name/ folder, but it would also be the simplest to fool with by renaming the partition or having another one with the same name, causing the mount point to be modified.

°° It would be appropriate to use a temporary file storing the result of the last execution to avoid killing the Finder if *another* disk was to be [un]mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work reliably, but you could try saving a property list like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/showall_external.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>showall_external</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>k=com.apple.Finder\ AppleShowAllFiles
sleep 3
if [[ -d /Volumes/WD/ ]]; then
    if [[ $(defaults read $k) = 0 ]]; then
        defaults write $k -bool true
        osascript -e 'quit app "Finder"'
    fi
else
    if [[ $(defaults read $k) = 1 ]]; then
        defaults write $k -bool false
        osascript -e 'quit app "Finder"'
    fi
fi</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Volumes/WD/</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It can be loaded with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/showall_external.plist` or by logging out and back in.

Without the sleep command /Volumes/WD/ sometimes existed when the volume was being unmounted. The program is also run when files under /Volumes/WD/ are modified, so it checks the current value of the key first. The program gets throttled if it has been run in the last 10 seconds, so there can be a delay of up to 10 seconds before it is run.

[ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) can run a script when a USB device is attached, but I couldn't figure out how to run a script when a USB device is disconnected or a volume is ejected.